# Programmatically set WinRt button content to image

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

For a given button control in Winrt I want to dynamically set it's content to an image. I would have thought this would be dead simple:

```
 _subjectFilePoster = new BitmapImage();
 _subjectFilePoster.SetSource(t);
 _btnPlayVideo.Content = _subjectFilePoster;
```

But it's not, instead I get a button with the typename `Windows.Ui.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage` written on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to set its `Content` to `<Image>` and the `<Image>`'s `Source` to the `BitmapImage`

```C#
_subjectFilePoster = new BitmapImage();
_subjectFilePoster.SetSource(t);

Image i = new Image();
i.Source = _subjectFilePoster;

_btnPlayVideo.Content = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it:

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton">
    <Image Source="{Binding}" />
</Button>
```

With this:

```
this.MyButton.DataContext = "http://server/image.png";
```

Why does it work? Because you get to use the native type converter in the underlying XAML framework. It's the easiest way to do it. It certainly works. I use this technique all the time.

You can do it like this:

```
<Button>
    <Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="{Binding}" />
</Button>
```

Then with this:

```
this.MyImage.DataContext = "http://server/image.png";
```

Is it the only way? No. Is it the easiest way? Yes.

The best of both words: binding and code-behind.

Best of luck!